# MYSql stored procedure..Retrieve rows and check

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a table with Ids. The ids are linked to other tables which have description for Ids. I need to write a query which will fetch  the description for the corresponding Ids. The table has 4 ids and 4000 records, which means 4 description for 4000 records at one go.
To my knowledge I assume it can be done using stored procedure. I am also new to stored procedure.
Any help appreciated. I am using mysql.

Comment: how can we help without schema & sample data?

Comment: Welcome to SO, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: From what you tell, you need a join, not a stored procedure. But without more information we can't tell anything.